# checking countable additivity for a probability measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(p_{x})_{x \in X}$ be a family of real numbers indexed by the finite or countable set $X$. We assume that $p_x \geq 0 $ and $\sum_{x \in X} p_x = 1$. Now, We define the probability measure $P(A) = \sum_{x \in A} p_x $. I want to show that if $\{ A_i \}$ is a countable family of measurable sets (pairwise disjoint), then

$$ P( \bigcup A_i ) = \sum P(A_i)$$

So, if $X$ is finite, then the collection $\{ A_i \}$ is a finite collection, say $A_1,...,A_n$. So ,

$$ P( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i ) = \sum_{x \in \bigcup^n A_i } p_x$$

Here I am stuck. How can I break this sum? Also, does this also works for the countable case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about $$\sum_{x\in \bigcup^n A_i} p_x = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{x\in A_i} p_x?$$
Every summand on the left is on the right, and there are no repeats because the $A_i$ are disjoint.